# Pandas keeps creating lists instead of DataFrames out of HTML input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I used the requests module to create an HTML object out of the contents of a webpage. I tried to use pandas to read_html on that object, but it just created a giant list. It looks like a dataframe, but the type says list, and I can't call dataframe methods on it.

This is the code I wrote for it after getting the HTML object:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.google}

tables = pd.read_html(response.content)
```

This is what it looks like when I call tables:

[image: Table]

It looks right, and I can fix the bad data once it's in the form of a dataframe, but I can't figure out how to change it from type list to type dataframe, and I'm also not sure why it went into a list instead of a dataframe in the first place.

As a second note, I tried using BeautifulSoup to read the HTML and extract the table which gave me just the contents of the table, but when I try to read it via pandas, if I try to pd.read_html(str(table)) and then preview the dataframe, I just get the site name and the bottom content in a list, not a dataframe.

Comment: Try `tables[0]`?

Comment: That worked! I didn't realize it would be creating a list of DataFrames, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.read_html` is returning a list of dataframes.

Try:

```
 tables[0]
```

---

Experimenting with Google's Colaboratory.

[Code runs here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KHpS1HGljiQlv6f86Zqn8qoOs280wH7d)

[Notebook can be found on my github here](https://github.com/pirsquared/Colaboratory/blob/master/Pandas_keeps_creating_lists_instead_of_DataFrames_out_of_HTML_input.ipynb)